# How to put a (Start) Menu button on Fluxbox Toolbar

Tags: menu, window-manager, fluxbox

I often run programs maximized (leaving no desktop area). I want to be able to use my mouse alone to open the menu, and my mouse has no scroll wheel. I'm just going for a simple old school windows look.

How can I put a menu button on the fluxbox toolbar?

Answer (score 3):

In your `$HOME/.fluxbox/init` file, look for the line that defines the tools on your toolbar, and add a "RootMenu" item where you want it to appear.  Here's what mine looks like:

```
session.screen0.toolbar.tools:  RootMenu, iconbar, systemtray, clock
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: **Solution at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3551120&group_id=35398&atid=413963#**

---

there's the Fluxbox Tray Menu http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftmenu/
but unfortunately it has to be in the system tray...

right now I'm using "Mod4 Mouse3 :RootMenu" and "OnToolbar Mouse2 :RootMenu" in my keys file

Comment: I give you a thumbs up for effort. I decided to go with lxpanel instead because of it's better interface and applets.

Comment: @Sepero I submitted a feature request at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3551120&group_id=35398&atid=413963

Answer (score 0):

At this time 2018 the only way to install ftmenu in Ubuntu 18.04 are installing this dependences:

```
sudo apt-get install git libgtk2.0-dev
```

next put one by one in command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/taq/ftmenu
cd ftmenu
./configure
make
sudo su
make install
```

Then run in terminal with:

```
ftmenu
```

you obtain this:

[image: snapshot ftmenu in Ubuntu 18.04]

But the only problem is that some icons are big

Well, to obtain this menu firt is neccesary to install xdgmenumaker with this:

```
sudo apt-get install git txt2tags
git clone https://github.com/gapan/xdgmenumaker
cd xdgmenumaker
make
sudo su
make install
```

Then you need to follow this steps:

1.- Edit "menu" file under .fluxbox hidden folder:

```
gedit ~/.fluxbox/menu
```

2.- Delete manually all text and copy and paste this:

```
[begin] (fluxbox)
[include] (~/.fluxbox/xdg_menu)
   [config] (Configuration)
   [workspaces] (Workspaces)
   [reconfig] (Reconfigure)
   [restart] (Restart)
   [exec] (Update Fluxbox Menu) {xdgmenumaker -i -s16 -f fluxbox > ~/.fluxbox/xdg_menu}
   [exit] (Exit)
[end]
```

save and close

3.- Restart fluxbox or close session.

4.- Activate menu, right clic in desktop and clic in "Update Fluxbox Menu"

[image: Activate menu]

Here an snapshot of all menu apps when you give right clic:

[image: snapshot of menu apps graphics]

God Bless